# Store variable from one event handler to be used by another event handler in Javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, dom-events

Imagine this Javascript code:

```
"use strict";

   var codePc = function (){        
   var code=[ ];    
   // code not important
   // code not important for the question: print the values to an html list    
    Return code

var codePlayer = function (list1){              
   var Intrud = [ ];    
   // code not important
   //code not important for the question: print the values to an html list    
    Return intrud
        
var codeCompare = function (list2){    
   var equal = [ ];    
   // code not important for the question: it should compare list 1 with list2
   // code not important for the question: print the values to an html list    
    Return equal


function main(){ 
    
   document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){codePc ();});    
   document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){codePlayer (code);}); //line 2    
   document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){codeCompare (intrud);});            
 };   


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ main()});
```

When I click on button1, I run the function `codePC`. The function returns code.

When I click on button2, I run the function `codePlayer`. The function returns intrud.

When I click on button3, I run the function `codeCompare`. The function returns equal.

How can I use the var code, produced when I clicked on button 1, to feed the function when I click in the button 1?

How can I save the variables code, intrud and equal, as global variables for later use?

When I run the 3 function by this way, it is possible to save the lists in a variable?

I just can't do :

```
Var codeKeep = document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){codePc ();});
```

Comment: Yes, store them in a global state variable.

Comment: But how can I do it?